# Custom Options deleted after saving products programatically

Tags: magento2, custom-options, magento2.4.2

In Magento 2.4.2, when i am going to update products programmatically, it's removed customizable options automatically
Below code for your reference:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
foreach ($collection as $product){
   $product->save();
}
```

It's automatically removed existing customizable options

Before executing above code
[image]
After executing above code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

got the resolution for this issue

Need to update product using product repository model

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
```

Like below

```
$objectManager      = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollection  = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $productRepository  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $collection         = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                            ->addFieldToFilter('type_id','simple')
                                            ->load();

    foreach ($collection as $product){
        
        $productRepository->save($product);     
    }
```